# Why can't I find ansible when I install it using setup.py?

Tags: python, macos, installation, pip, setup.py

Because I had some trouble with Ansible (I'm on mac) which seemed to be fixed in the latest dev version today I uninstalled ansible through pip (`sudo pip uninstall ansible`) and reinstalled the latest dev version from the github repo using the classic setup.py method, which seemed to end successfully ([full output here](http://pasted.co/0a000255/fullscreen.php?hash=9ce9d12b8ea726b3473b62225c22f408&toolbar=true&linenum=false).

So then I tried using it:

```
$ ansible --version
-bash: ansible: command not found
$ which ansible
$
```

I checked where it is installed. From the full output I linked to above I found that it is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, and indeed in there I find an egg:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages | grep ansible
drwxr-xr-x    4 root    admin     136 Aug 22 16:33 ansible-2.4.0-py2.7.egg
```

When I start Python and check the site-packages folder I find a different folder:

```
>>> import site; print site.getsitepackages()[0]
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

but that is a symlink to the same folder:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
lrwxr-xr-x  1 hielke  admin  54 Aug 13 22:36 /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages -> ../../../../../../../../../lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

So I guess the problem is that no symlink is created to the ansible package in `/usr/local/bin/`. But I'm unsure how I could create such a symlink and why it wouldn't appear in the first place.

Does anybody know how I can move forward from here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Can you show your environment variable, I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: @aristotll - I'm not sure which environment variable you mean, but to be sure, here's a full paste of `os.environ`: https://pastebin.com/b0AuuAaV Does that tell you anything?

Comment: Can you show the result of `which python`?

Comment: @aristotll - `/usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: What exactly is your objective? There are multiple problems: `Cellar` is Homebrew, running `sudo pip` invokes Apple-provided Python, this question is off-topic for StackOverflow, etc. etc.

Comment: @techraf - Why doesn't sudo pip invoke the python installed by homebrew? Since `which python` gives me the homebrew installed Python I guess pip should also install it in the homebrew installed Python. And even if it would install in the Apple-provided Python, why doesn't it work, and why doesn't the `ansible` command work?

Comment: Because paths differ. On top of that, using Homebrew with `sudo` is not recommended. It doesn't work, because each Python instance uses it's own paths. You have a mess on your system and cleaning up macOS is not programming, hence the question is far off-topic. Use any of virtual environment managers for Python and forget about problems.

Comment: @techraf - I never used `sudo` with homebrew. I only used `sudo` with pip, which should be no problem. I understand there should be something wrong on my system. If it doesn't belong here; any idea where it fits better?

Comment: It is a problem, because you are calling Apple-provided one. I already tried to explain that. I also asked about your objective: if the question is how to clean up, then the answer is: reinstall macOS.

Comment: @techraf - The weird thing is that pip does seem to call the brew installed python. When I do `cat $(which pip)`, the first line of the file reads `#!/usr/local/bin/python` which is a symlink to the brew installed Python: `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python` gives me `/usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/bin/python`. I think the main problem is that no symlink is created in `/user/local/bin/` to the ansible package. But I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: The only weird thing I find here is your insistence on using Python outside of a virtual environment.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you invoke `ansible` from the shell, bash will search in your `$PATH` for a file named ansible that is executable.  This may not be the only issue, but this is the immediate cause for the error you're seeing.  The `.egg` file itself is not an executable, it's just a file used for distributing the code.

If ansible has been installed correctly, you should be able to find it by using [locate](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/02/enable-and-use-the-locate-command-in-the-mac-os-x-terminal/) or the OSX Finder GUI.  The name should match exactly, with no file extensions.  You will probably also find `ansible-connection`, `ansible-console`, etc. in the same place where you find the `ansible` executable.  If you find it, great!  Test it out and add that directory to your `$PATH` in a terminal like so:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/ansible
```

Where `/path/to/ansible` is the directory where you found the executables.  This change to the `$PATH` variable is temporary, and will go away when you close your shell. If you can now run ansible from bash, then you can make the change permanent by adding that export to the end of your `$HOME/.bash_profile` file, or by adding a rule in `/etc/paths.d` (recommended by Apple).  See more on how exactly to do those [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/) if you are unfamiliar with them.

Now, if that's not the problem and you can't find the `ansible` executable, then the installation itself is your problem.  You might also try using a virtual environment (if you have it installed) to make sure that the version you're pulling from github isn't broken:

```
git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git
cd ansible
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install .
which ansible
```

As of this writing, the above gives me a working `ansible` install.

Comment: I didn't know the `locate` command, and it was very helpful. It found me the following executable file which I can manually call to run ansible: `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/ansible`. Should I now manually create a symlink to that file in `/usr/local/bin/`, should I add the folder `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/` to my path, or do you have yet another suggestion?

Comment: You can either manually create the symlink [like so](http://osxdaily.com/2015/08/06/make-symbolic-links-command-line-mac-os-x/), or you can add the `/usr/loca/Cellar/.../2.7/bin` folder to your `$PATH` variable like I mentioned in the post.  I would recommend the second approach if you use pip to install more than just ansible, but the symlink is fine if you only want ansible.

Comment: Awesome, that solved it, plus I learned another thing or two. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

For those using the Windows 10 Ubuntu terminal, running this command should fix the issue:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

Comment: this question is for macOS

Comment: quick note that this solution works as well if you are having fun on chrome os linux subsystem!

Answer (score 19):

Find where ansible reside on your Mac. Most times its `/Users/<yourusername>/Library/Python/3.7/bin` 
or `/Users/<yourusername>/Library/Python/2.7/bin`. Then ...

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<yourusername>/Library/Python/3.7/bin
```

You can store this in your `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I think you just need to create a soft link

`ln -s /Users/${yourname}/Library/Python/${python version}/bin/ansible /usr/local/bin/ansible`

Answer (score 5):

```
pip3 install ansible --user
```

this installs in ~/.local. just include this in PATH, it will work
example: `export PATH="$PATH:~/.local/bin"`

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue when I installed ansible. Run the below commands to solve the issue. But we have to active each time when we open a bash session if we want to use ansible.

```
$ python -m virtualenv ansible 
$ source ansible/bin/activate
$ pip install ansible
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using zsh so in my `/Users/arojas/.zshrc` I add this line that's where my Ansible got installed by Python

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Library/Python/3.7/bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and after have installed it used `pip3 install ansible` it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest uninstalling Ansible and re-installing it using `pip` according to [the method suggested in the Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-pip):

> Or if you are looking for the latest development version:
>
> `pip install git+https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git@devel`
>
> If you are installing on OS X Mavericks, you may encounter some noise from your compiler. A workaround is to do the following:
>
> `$ sudo CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments pip install ansible`
>
> Readers that use virtualenv can also install Ansible under virtualenv, though we’d recommend to not worry about it and just install Ansible globally. Do not use easy_install to install ansible directly.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! Your first suggestion `pip install git..` runs without problems, but afterwards the command `ansible --version` still gives me `-bash: ansible: command not found`, even though I can `import ansible` from within Python perfectly. After uninstalling it (again successfully) I tried your second suggestion, which finished successfully, but also gave me a `-bash: ansible: command not found` even though `import ansible` from within Python also worked perfectly. I guess it's just a symlink from within `/usr/local/bin/` is missing and I have no idea how to create it. Any idea?

Comment: @kramer65 Have you tried running it from a new shell after installing? Or if installing inside a virtualenv, deactivate it and activate again, or just run it directly from the binaries sub-directory of the virtualenv (`Scripts` on Windows, `bin` otherwise).

Answer (score -1):

```
      system/instance used: ec2 RH8, as root
      # pip3 install ansible           (not recommended - should be by a user) 
      # ansible --version              ( not found - wtf?!)
      # yum install mlocate
      # update
      # locate ansible                 (long output; scroll to where you input command)
      # export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin     
      # ansible --version               (success, Yes!)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  system/instance used: ec2 RH8, as root
  # pip3 install ansible           (not recommended - should be by a user) 
  # ansible --version              ( not found - :( )
  # yum install mlocate
  # updatedb (updatedb creates or updates a database used by locate)
  # locate ansible (TL;DR)
  # export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin (Add this line to .bashrc)
  # source .bashrc (To reflect the changes in the bash)  
  # ansible --version               (success, Yes!)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. I have no idea how this is supposed to answer the question.